# HTTP 503 error when behind ZScaler corporate proxy and trying to access web app

Tags: c#, .net, iis, networking, asp.net-mvc-5

A couple of days ago our web app started showing a 503 error when trying to access our web app. It works fine when ZScaler is off. This is an old app running .NET MVC 5 on a Windows Server 2012 machine. No changes were made from our side when the issue started happening, so I was suspecting that the networking team had done something. However, they cannot seem to locate the issue.

When trying to access the page through Chrome, I get a HTTP 503 error, but on Firefox it shows a blank page and says that the connection is not secure. I can access the web app through the server hostname URL fine. However, when trying to use the registered domain name, it is displaying this error. I have checked the logs on the server, but it isn't showing anything specific to this error.

Does anyone know what this could be? Is there anything in IIS that I should look at specifically?

I have checked the logs on the server, but it isn't showing anything specific to this error.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 503 error usually indicates that the server is currently not able to handle the request due to maintenance or capacity issues. It could be caused due to many factors, like a server outage, an issue with the network, or a problem with the application itself.

Here are a few things you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check the IIS logs, IIS logs are located in the
   C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles folder by default.
2. Check the event logs, event logs can be accessed through the
   Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc).
3. Try accessing the web app using the server's IP address instead of
   the registered domain name. This can help determine if the issue is
   related to the domain name or the server itself.
4. Make sure that the application pool for the web app is running and
   that the application pool identity has the necessary permissions to
   access the web app's files and resources.
5. Check the network configuration and make sure that the server is
   properly connected to the network and that there are no issues with
   the network connection.
6. Check the web.config to make sure that it is properly
   set up and that there are no issues with the web.config file.
7. Check the ZScaler configuration to make sure that it is not
   blocking access to the web app. You may need to work with the
   networking team to determine if there are any issues with the
   ZScaler configuration.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

1. There is nothing in the logs that hints towards what it could be.
2. The event viewer does not either indicate that something is off. The only error I can see there is something that has been around for years.
3. This works. The issue is that I cannot go through the registered domain when connected through ZScaler, but once I turn it off or try to hit the IP directly, it works.

I cannot understand where the issue could be, as we have not changed anything on our side when this started happening, so web.config etc. are still good.